# Eigenvalues of Product of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices, then it is known that
$\lambda(AB)=\lambda(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})$, where $\lambda(X)$ denotes the ordered eigenvalues of $X$. How does one prove this result?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sqrt AB\sqrt Av =\lambda v$. If $\lambda\ne0$, then $\sqrt Av\ne0$, and $AB (\sqrt Av) = \lambda \sqrt Av$. If $\lambda=0$ and $\sqrt Av\ne0$ then similarly $AB (\sqrt Av) =0$. 
In the case $\lambda=0$ and $\sqrt Av=0$ it follows that $A$ is not invertible, hence $AB$ is not invertible, and $0\in \lambda(AB)$.

This proves $\lambda( \sqrt AB\sqrt A ) \subset \lambda(AB)$.

Let now $ABv=\lambda v$. If $\lambda \ne0$ then $v = \lambda^{-1}\sqrt A(\sqrt ABv)$ and 
$$
\sqrt AB\sqrt A(\sqrt ABv) = \sqrt ABABv = \lambda (\sqrt ABv),
$$
hence $\lambda \in \lambda(\sqrt AB\sqrt A)$. If $\lambda=0$ then $A$ or $B$ are not invertible, and hence $\sqrt AB\sqrt A$ is not invertible, hence $0$ is an eigenvalue.

This proves the reverse inclusion $\lambda(AB)\subset \lambda(\sqrt AB\sqrt A)$.